# No lock screen waking up from suspend

Tags: suspend, lock-screen

When I wake up from suspend, it directly opens my desktop, no lockscreen.

I don't understand why I no longer have the option to change the lock settings.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

[image]

Comment: Did you set a password for the user account in question?